# how to get current playback time in video.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I am using [video.js](http://videojs.com/) project to play videos on my web page.
I implemented it perfectly on my web page but i required to retrieve the video's current playing time how can i do that ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
var whereYouAt = myPlayer.currentTime();
```

https://docs.videojs.com/player#currentTime

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked using the method call not calling the attribute:

```
var whereYouAt = myPlayer.currentTime();
```

I just wanted to add this for anyone else having the same issue, even though this answer refers clearly to the accepted one.